# Is MySql.Data.xml needed?

Tags: mysql, xml, installation, c++-cli

I am about to finish my first windows forms application with C++CLI. It connects to MySQL database. When I compiled it, in the release folder appeared **MySql.Data.dll**, so I assume when I pack things up for letting people install my application, I need to include it? What about **MySql.Data.xml**, does my application need it? Same goes with **System.Core.dll** and **System.Core.xml**.

Comment: Whoa, I suggest you ask this in the context of writing an installer and so [edit] your question with that information and technology tags. Towards an answer: Build output folders are for: 1) a place to find the outputs, 2) a place to launch a debug session, and _then_ other purposes.